# Rebol: problem with not enough memory

Tags: rebol

I have run this program below with a symbol_list of a few hundreds symbol and at some moment it says not enough memory whereas I do reuse the same variable why ?

```
base-url: http://www.google.com/finance/historical
download-directory: "askpoweruser/stock-download/google/files/"
column-header: "Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume"
#debug: true

symbol_list: parse/all {GOOG AAPL MSFT INDEXDJX:.DJI} " "
ans: ask {symbols by default "GOOG AAPL MSFT INDEXDJX:.DJI": }
if (ans <> "") [symbol_list: parse/all ans " "]
;do code-block/2

foreach symbol symbol_list [
  url0: rejoin [base-url "?q=" symbol]
  dir: make-dir/deep to-rebol-file download-directory

  either none? filename: find symbol ":" [
    filename: symbol
    url: rejoin [url0 "&output=csv"]

    either not error? try [content: read url][
      out-string: copy rejoin [column-header newline]
      quotes: parse/all content ",^/"
      reversed-quotes: reverse quotes

      foreach [v c l h o d] reversed-quotes [
          either not (error? try [d: to-date d]) [
              d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
              append out-string rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline]
          ][
              ;print [d "is not a date"]
              ;input
          ]

      ]
      filename: rejoin [filename "_" "1440"]
      write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename ".csv"] out-string
      print filename
    ][
      print ["Error for symbol" symbol]
    ]
  ][
    filename: replace/all replace/all filename ":" "" "." ""
    out: copy []
    for i 0 1 1 [
      p: i
      url: rejoin [url0 "&start=" (p * 200) "&num=" ((p + 1) * 200)]
      content: read url
      rule: [to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
          to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
          to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
          copy quotes to </table> to end
      ]
      parse content rule

      parse quotes [
          some [to "<td" thru "<td" to ">" thru ">" [copy x to "<" | copy x to end] (append out replace/all x "^/" "")]
          to end
      ]
      if #debug [
          write/lines to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_" p ".html"] quotes
      ]

    ]
    if #debug [
        write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_temp" ".txt"] mold out
    ]
    out-string: copy rejoin [column-header newline]
    out: reverse out    

    foreach [v c l h o d] out [
       d: parse/all d " ,"
       d: to-date rejoin [d/4 "-" d/1 "-" d/2]
       d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
       append out-string replace/all rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline] "," ""
    ]
    filename: rejoin [filename "_" "1440"]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename ".csv"] out-string
    print filename
  ]

]
```

To get the list of symbols you can use this (rebol crashed above before letter H):

```
alphabet: [A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z]
symbol-list: copy []
rule: [
    to <table class="quotes">
    some [ to {<A href="/stockquote} to ">" thru ">" copy symbol to "<" (append symbol-list symbol)]
    to </table>
]
foreach letter alphabet [
    content: read to-url rejoin ["http://www.eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/" letter ".htm"]
parse content rule
probe symbol-list
write/append %askpoweruser/stock-download/symbol-list-nyse.txt mold symbol-list
]
```

Comment: Your code works on my machine, and happily populates symbol-list with 3492 entries. Can you let us know [1] what version of REBOL. [2] What platform (Win, MAC, etc). and [3] What the error message is? Thanks,

Comment: I use REBOL/View 2.7.7.3.1 1-Jan-2010 I pasted the symbols from clipboard to console on a 4 Go RAM machine on Windows 7.

Comment: The error message is what I said in title: not enough memory.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty close to what I successfully ran it on, so not sure I can help any further. You might want to raise a RAMBO (REBOL 2 bug database) report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can put a 'STAT function within one of your loops to try and figure out if and where a memory leak is occuring.

out of memory errors usually occur in one of these situations or something similar:

- appending to a series which is not cleared or copied at the start of a function with a loop
- a complete tree of data is not reset to none (at each leaf and branch) in a situation where some (a single?) sub elements are referenced outside the tree and the whole data block ends up being caught in the ram unable to free itself
- when printing a very large string or nested tree of large objects (for example a VID face contains a reference to the complete styleshet, so printing the window of a big app usually fails.).
- some stack overflows (endless recursions or loops) are sometimes incorrectly reported as memory errors.
- allocation of a single item grows exponentially... like image! allocation when multiplying each pass by 10 on both axes... effectively increasing two orders of magnitude which usually fails at numbers in the n*10k range.
- the largest item in the GC sometimes never deallocates as per the suboptimal R2 GC (large images *may* have this symptom).
- recursive parse rules are creating data and a single rule is infinite (it happens very rapidly on rules like [ rule | none ] .  none effectively equivalent to forever in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It works without problems. but some notes:

```
instead:
read to-url rejoin ["http://www.eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/" letter]
you can use just:
read join http://www.eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/ letter

instead:
either not cond [1][2]
you should use:
either cond [2][1]

instead:
download-directory: "askpoweruser/stock-download/google/files/"
dir: make-dir/deep to-rebol-file download-directory
write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_temp" ".txt"] mold out

use:
download-directory: %askpoweruser/stock-download/google/files/
dir: make-dir/deep download-directory
write rejoin [dir filename %_temp.txt] mold out

what the hell means?!:
for i 0 1 1 [
      p: i
      url: rejoin [url0 "&start=" (p * 200) "&num=" ((p + 1) * 200)]
..
```